# Exclude selected fields in typeorm responses, exclude the password field

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have this TypeORM entity:

```
export class Users extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: bigint

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 32 })
  username: string

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 32 })
  password: string
}
```

when I use the method:

```
const data = await Users.find({})
```

I get all the users with their passwords.
I want to exclude the password field from the response.

According to the documentation, I found that you can specify the `select` option as follows:

```
const data = await Users.find({ select: { username: true, password: false } })
```

This works, However, this is just an example.

In my real case, the user table has over 26 columns.

And I don't want to list every column in the `select` options as

```
const data = await Users.find({ select: { 
   username: true, 
   firstName: true,
   lastName: true,
   // ... other 99,999,99+ columns
   // then eventually:
   password: false 
} })
```

Is there a simpler solution where I can simply do something like a pre-fetch middleware, or define that it should be excluded in the schema?

In mongoose, I used to write `password: { select: false }` inside the schema itself.

Are there any methods we can do for TypeORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New answer:

Well, it turned out, this feature is already supported in typeorm, all you have to do is to use the `select` option, you can find this option inside the `@Column` decorator, as follows:

```
export class Users extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string
 
  // ...etc
}
```

## Old answer:

I found a cool way for doing it.

```bash
$ npm i class-transformer
```

Then, in your entity:

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer'

export class Users extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: bigint

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 32 })
  username: string

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 32 })
  @Exclude()
  password: string
}
```

After that, in your code, whenever you fetch the data, before sending it to the client, convert the returned TypeORM class instances to POJO (Plan Old JavaScript Objects):

```
import { instanceToPlain } from 'class-transformer'
const data = await Users.find()
const dataPOJO = data.map((user) => instanceToPlain(user))
// now dataPOJO includes everything except the 'password' field.
```